# How to use python scrape MSN stock history?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am trying to learn how to scrape dynamic web data from 
https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/history/fi-a1xzim

The webpage calls the url below with javascript to return the records.
https://finance-services.msn.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=126.1.MSFT.NAS&chartType=1d&isETF=false&iseod=False&lang=en-US&isCS=true&isVol=true

I tried several ways, but still cannot get the records with python, and got "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied."

```
import urllib
import urllib.request

 # url='https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/history/nas-msft/fi-a1xzim'

url='https://finance-services.msn.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=126.1.MSFT.NAS&chartType=1d&isETF=false&iseod=False&lang=en-US&isCS=true&isVol=true'

hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36', 
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive',
       }

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
content = page.read()
print (content)
```

What should I do to get the data, which we can see on website, from python?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are trying to access resource which is forbidden. If your intention only for learning try some other sites which allows scrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find success changing the headers like the following. Give this a go:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://finance-services.msn.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=126.1.MSFT.NAS&chartType=1d&isETF=false&iseod=False&lang=en-US&isCS=true&isVol=true'

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 
    'Referer': 'https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/history/fi-a1xzim', 
}

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(page.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use Selenium to scrape rather than trying to make a get request. You need to install chromedriver or another browser's driver, then install selenium. When you scrape it will open a browser, you can also run it headless with options.

[This](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-python-8a60f4cf40ab) Medium article should help you. Here's a quick sample:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    url='https://finance-services.msn.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=126.1.MSFT.NAS&chartType=1d&isETF=false&iseod=False&lang=en-US&isCS=true&isVol=true'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('Path in your computer where you have installed chromedriver')

    resp = driver.get(url)

    #do something
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will also give it a try.